# How to move a node in XML data using Perl

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I've tried several different methods for parsing XML documents. I need to find a node in the document with an `x`attribute, and then move that node with its children to a different parent node.

I've had some success using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML) for locating the node and being able to iterate through it's children, but I'm stuck in how to move it to a different parent.

Using `$node->cloneNode(1)` looks promising but I can't find good examples of its use.

This is the original XML data

```
<config logdir="/var/log/foo/" debugfile="/tmp/foo.debug">
  <old>
    <server name="sahara" osname="solaris" osversion="2.6">
      <address ip="10.0.0.101">Private</address>
      <address ip="10.0.1.101">Private</address>
    </server>
    <server name="gobi" osname="irix" osversion="6.5">
      <address ip="10.0.0.102">Private</address>
    </server>
    <server name="kalahari" osname="linux" osversion="2.0.34">
      <address ip="10.0.0.103">Private</address>
      <address ip="10.0.1.103">Private</address>
    </server>
  </old>
  <new>
  </new>        
</config>
```

and this is the result I would like

```
<config logdir="/var/log/foo/" debugfile="/tmp/foo.debug">
  <old>
    <server name="sahara" osname="solaris" osversion="2.6">
      <address ip="10.0.0.101">Private</address>
      <address ip="10.0.1.101">Private</address>
    </server>
    <server name="gobi" osname="irix" osversion="6.5">
      <address ip="10.0.0.102">Private</address>
    </server>
  </old>
  <new>
    <server name="kalahari" osname="linux" osversion="2.0.34">
      <address ip="10.0.0.103">Private</address>
      <address ip="10.0.1.103">Private</address>
    </server>
  </new>        
</config>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"a node with an 'x' attribute"*? Are you saying that you want to move the `server` element with a `name` attribute of `kalahari`?

Comment: Please show the Perl code that you have tried

Comment: Excellent.  This is perfect. Thank you both!  Yes Borodin, as in this example, match some attribute, like name or ip.  I don't have example code for moving as I had no idea where to start :/  I can definitely run with this.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml( IO => \*DATA );

my ($new) = $xml->findnodes('//new');

for my $linux ( $xml->findnodes('//old/server[@osname="linux"]') ) {
    $linux->unbindNode();         # Remove from Parent (done automatically when added elsewhere without cloning)
    $new->addChild($linux);
}

print $xml;

__DATA__
<config logdir="/var/log/foo/" debugfile="/tmp/foo.debug">
    <old>
        <server name="sahara" osname="solaris" osversion="2.6">
            <address ip="10.0.0.101">Private</address>
            <address ip="10.0.1.101">Private</address>
        </server>
        <server name="gobi" osname="irix" osversion="6.5">
            <address ip="10.0.0.102">Private</address>
        </server>
        <server name="kalahari" osname="linux" osversion="2.0.34">
            <address ip="10.0.0.103">Private</address>
            <address ip="10.0.1.103">Private</address>
        </server>
    </old>
    <new>
    </new>      
</config>
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config logdir="/var/log/foo/" debugfile="/tmp/foo.debug">
    <old>
        <server name="sahara" osname="solaris" osversion="2.6">
            <address ip="10.0.0.101">Private</address>
            <address ip="10.0.1.101">Private</address>
        </server>
        <server name="gobi" osname="irix" osversion="6.5">
            <address ip="10.0.0.102">Private</address>
        </server>

    </old>
    <new>
    <server name="kalahari" osname="linux" osversion="2.0.34">
            <address ip="10.0.0.103">Private</address>
            <address ip="10.0.1.103">Private</address>
        </server></new>      
</config>
```

Comment: There's no need to `unbindNode`

Comment: Aye.  I noticed that after positing, but figured it was still helpful to demonstrate how to explicitly remove from parent.  Added comment to be explicit

Comment: Question:
What is the significance of the `my ()` when declaring:
`my ($new) = $xml->findnodes('//new');`
as opposed to just `my $new`?

Comment: findnodes returns a list.  In order to get the first element of the list instead of the count of matched nodes, it is necessary to put the left hand side in a list context as well.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is find both the child node and the parent, and move the child to its new parent with a call to `appendChild`.

Supposing your original XML data is in a file called `config.xml`, the code would look like this.

I don't know of a better way to persuade `XML::LibXML` to produce nicely-indented data. The best I have found is to enable `no_blanks` and use a non-zero parameter to `toString`, but as you can see it's far from ideal.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'config.xml', no_blanks => 1);

my ($kalahari) = $xml->findnodes('/config/old/server[@name="kalahari"]');

my ($new) = $xml->findnodes('/config/new');

$new->appendChild($kalahari);

print $xml->toString(1);
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config logdir="/var/log/foo/" debugfile="/tmp/foo.debug">
  <old>
    <server name="sahara" osname="solaris" osversion="2.6">
      <address ip="10.0.0.101">Private</address>
      <address ip="10.0.1.101">Private</address>
    </server>
    <server name="gobi" osname="irix" osversion="6.5">
      <address ip="10.0.0.102">Private</address>
    </server>
  </old>
  <new>
  <server name="kalahari" osname="linux" osversion="2.0.34"><address ip="10.0.0.103">Private</address><address ip="10.0.1.103">Private</address></server></new>
</config>
```

Comment: `no_blanks` is mostly a hack. To get nicely formatted output, `XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint` is probably the best choice.

Comment: @nwellnhof: I looked at that, but I don't see any reason why `XML::LibXML` shouldn't be able to do it by itself. I don't like that there is a whole other module that is effectively a work-around. By the way the link is [`XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint)